# How can I use octave function minimizers in c++?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression, optimization, octave

I have downloaded and built octave library and it works fine . But I cannot call function minimizers like `fminunc()` , `fmingc()` etc to minimize my functions for performing logistic regression or using it in neural networks . Can these functions be accessed from c++ ? If yes, then how ?

Comment: What is the "octave library" you have downloaded and built? Do you mean the octave application or something else? Have you looked at the documentation, specifically ".oct" files which let you link C++ into Octave, and let you call Octave native functions from C++? Are you trying to write a standalone C++ application? Or what? Can you show us some sample code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a native library in C++ for optimization. Check out this one :
[dlib](http://dlib.net/optimization.html)

Comment: Which function in this library is equivalent to fminunc and fmingc functions of octave ?